# What are good MSE and RMSE for my normalized dataset to between 0 and 1

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

I using a training source CSV file raed into a master dataframe that I split into 80% training data and 20% test data. Before I split the data I normalized all columns of the dataframe to have all the independent and dependent data to be between 0 and 1, including the targets (dependent variables). In my results after training my predicted values all read between 0 and 1. I then de-normalize a single prediction to see what value I get and compare to the expected value. My question is I'm measuring the model by MSE (mean squared error) and RMSE (root mean squared error). My MSE and RMSE on my training data are 0.03 and 0.16, respectively. Are these acceptable values with a normalized data source? If not, with my normalized data source, what would be acceptable values? Or should I be normalizing my data because I don't have huge differences of range differences between my independent variables? If I don't normalize my data should I then use a Normalized RMSE to interpret the metric? If I normalize the RMSE when not normalizing the training and test data, what would be an acceptable value for the Normalized RMSE? Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Good” should be measure relative to a naive forecast (such as a random walk). That benchmark will vary according to the degree of volatility in the data. .5 might be terrible for one forecast and excellent for another.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that.